# .NET MVC 3: model annotations don't work

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a very strange problem. I have Visual Studio 2010 with MVC 3. My OS is Windows Server 2008 64bit. The problem is that when I try to annotate a model with validation attributes they just don't work. Only the Required attribute works. I tried to launch the sample project that is shipped with MVC 3. It has Email validation attribute and it doesn't work too. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Also please clarify "don't work". Do you mean client-side validation, server-side validation, the web site does not show anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question on the official MVC forum and they answered that Email validation attribute has not yet implemented, so I need to user Regexp validator instead. Thanks for your answers anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the RTM of MVC3?  The RC had some issues with getting some of the data annotations to run properly and needed a hack.  In the RTM, this was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC3, you can use the DataType annotation to specify the data type as "email":

[DataType(DataType.Email)]

If you're using this in conjunction with jQuery and the unobtrusive validation script that ships with MVC3, then you will get email validation without resorting to regular expressions.

Note: I just discovered today that the email validation performed by the DataType annotation fails when the email address starts with a number, such as "1234Something@domain.com".  Far as I can tell, this is a valid email address according to the RFC, but it fails the validation test.